# Dropdown menu with parent linked issue on tablet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu with parent items all linked and also child and sub-child items that work on :hover to open the dropdown sub-items.

Every item (parents and childs) are also linked. Everything works fine on desktop because on mouse over the parent item the dropdown is opened and I can choose to click on the parent item link or on one of the dropdown that appeared with the mouseover.

The issue is on tablet device. In this case if I tap on the parent item then it just redirects me to the link of this menu item instead of opening the dropdown with child items.

So for tablet I would have a double tap for parent (and also sub-parents): first tap on the parent item open the dropdown, second tap always on the parent item fires it's link.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

hover function will work only on desktop. For tabs and mobiles you have to use click function by using jQuery / Javascript

Example :

```
<style>
    li ul{display:none;}
</style>

<ul class="parent">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <ul class="child">
            <li>Home1</li>
            <li>Home2</li>
            <li>Home3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <ul class="child">
            <li>About1</li>
            <li>About2</li>
            <li>About3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul li").click(function(){
       $(".child").hide();
       $(this).find(".child").show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Any suggestion about the JS code? I'm not good with JS... :-)

Comment: I've tested it but don't work. the problem is that if you have a real link in the tag <a> it soon fires the link instead of opening the menu.